# Image Comparisons for detecting hand gestures

Tags: php, image, image-processing, comparison, image-comparison

Hey everyone I have been trying to work on a php powered webapp which would help the special persons in communication. 
So, the plan is 
1) There would be a live webcam where user would make gestures 
2) On 3 seconds of idle gesture a picture would be taken and saved
3) Now I have to compare this image with pre stored set of gestures so I can find best matching gesture images and based on that could find what gesture was it. 
I have managed till step 2 i.e. capturing image  and storing it, but need help in comparing it for finding best matching image. 
Any help would be appreciated ❤

Comment: May helpfull to you..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606736/image-comparison-in-php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what you have tried so far to solve your problem, so we have a basis to work with you toward your solution.