# Lengths of image hashes

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-comparison, imagehash

I'm developing an application that involves hashing of images and storing those hash values. Based on the links in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998662/what-is-image-hashing-used-for) and other research I have done, am I understanding correctly that most image hashes are 64 bits in length?

I do see some hashes supporting more than 64 bits. Do longer hashes offer any practical benefits, or are 64-bit hashes sufficient for most applications?

Comment: That depends on the purpose of the hash. For testing if two images are identical by comparing the hashes, 64 bits is enough (probability of 1 in 2^64 to get wrong result). For cryptographic hash (preventing someone from forging an image with the same hash), use more then 64 bits.

Comment: @Rotem Image hashes are used to determine if 2 images are similar, not necessarily identical. They're different from cryptographic hashes. My question is about image hashes, which are used for image searches.

Comment: This may be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/a/34608025/2836621

Comment: same question: https://forum.opencv.org/t/image-hash-length/8476